# Jquery Concatination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace the 'ul' and 'li' elements with the variables.

```
this.tableBody = 'ul';
this.tableRow = 'li';

var hasDifferentNumberOfRows = this.dataOriginalValueMap['originalSize'] !== $('#strategyTable ul li:not(:has(div.tableEmptyCell))').size();
```

Something like this:

```
var hasDifferentNumberOfRows = this.dataOriginalValueMap['originalSize'] !== $('#strategyTable' +  ' ' + this.tableBody + ' ' + this.tableCell + ':not(:has(div.tableEmptyCell))').size();
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the concatenation. Are you sure that's what's causing the problem?

Comment: Call me crazy but I always thought `ul` was an Unordered List, and `li` was a List Item... :D

Comment: I am not sure about this one:  li:not(:has(div.tableEmptyCell))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your li is tablerow variable not tablecell

```
var hasDifferentNumberOfRows = this.dataOriginalValueMap['originalSize'] !== $('#strategyTable' +  ' ' + this.tableBody + ' ' + this.tablerow + ':not(:has(div.tableEmptyCell))').size();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate it. HElped a lot)